# rutas Ionic3 navegador Ej:chrome

Tags: ionic3

Como puedo hacer para que todas las rutas mal escritas se vayan a una pagina, con el segment de la misma, es decir, si escribo (localhost/#/rrerewrwer) que se vaya al home con la url (localhost/#/home).
Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro ,pero segun la documentacion de angular routing,seria añadir el path "**" en el modulo app-routing.module.ts apuntando al componente donde quieres que vaya:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
{ path: 'detail', loadChildren: './detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule' },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```